# Eclipse Mingw won't run my makefile

Tags: eclipse, makefile, mingw

I have a makefile in the root of my folder but for some reason when I try to build the project  it never uses my makefile but instead tries to compile everything.

Comment: While creating your project, did you choose `New C/C++ project` or `Makefile project with existing code` ??

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem - i ended up using the "Make-Targets" feature provided by CDT
Maybe this can be considered a workaround rather than a real solution 
Anyway, i started using this approach in eclipse 3.2 and stuck with it ever since

1. Disable automatic build - anyway a good idea when working on larger projects
2. Enabling Make Targets: `Window/Show View/Make Targets`
3. Creating Make Targets: straight forward, just click `New Make Target` in the `Makefile View`, just be sure to disable the `Run all Project Builders` option
4. Start build Process by double-clicking the target

This allows the use of the compiler output-parsing feature and the associated highlighting of errors and warnings in the source code.
Anyhow i wasn't able to set up gdb based debugging this way